# How to get playlists a Dailymotion video is a member of?

Tags: dailymotion-api

I'm currently working on a project that uses daily motion as its video platform. It will contain several private playlists and videos and I need to be able to fetch video details including what playlist that video is a member of.

When querying the `/me/video/<VIDEO_ID>` endpoint, there is no field I can add to the `fields` query to retrieve a list of playlists and the `/video/<VIDEO_ID>/playlists` although undocumented, returns a 200 but with an empty list of results.

Using [this documentation](https://developer.dailymotion.com/api/#playlist-videos-connection), there seem to be no way to get a list of playlists a video is a member of, am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the right endpoint.
To get the list of playlists a video is a member of, you can use the video connection: `/video/<VIDEO_ID>/playlists`

This connection should be documented, we'll investigate on this issue

Comment: This is not documented but this also returns a 200 with an empty `list` property. I have mentioned, these videos are private, maybe that makes a difference. Although I tried both `/video/<VIDEO_ID>/playlists` and `/video/<PRIVATE_VIDEO_ID>/playlists`, neither work and both return a 200 with an empty `list` property

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've figured out the issue, the `video/<PRIVATE_VIDEO_ID>/playlists` endpoint works but the playlist must be public.

There is still a bit of an issue, if I want my video object to contain their playlists, I'll have to query the video endpoint to get the fields and then to query its playlists separately.

Scenario would be; I want to display a list of latest videos and their associated playlists, for each video, I'd have to first query `/video/<PRIVATE_VIDEO_ID>` with the fields I need (in this case, `title, private_id, duration, tags`) and also query `/video/<PRIVATE_VIDEO_ID>/playlists` in order to get its playlists `title`.

It would be significantly more efficient if I was able to query for the `playlists` field in the `/video/<PRIVATE_VIDEO_ID>` endpoint.